# Using datasource in a Java class file

Tags: java, datasource

I am using data source explorer in eclipse. the connection is setup and now I want to use it in the normal Java file. I have used the same datasource explorer in a JSP file.

As per [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html) under the web project section I have tried doing the same.

I tried creating a datasource object as per this Java code

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/mysqltest");
con = ds.getConnection();
```

but it throws an exception as follows

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at logic.Leave.(Leave.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.Leaveform_jsp._jspService(Leaveform_jsp.java:549)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the datasource in the datasource explorer has no influence on your server environment.

You will need to define the datasource in Tomcat: either in your `context.xml` or in the `server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to configure your JNDI properties for this datasource properly.
for example: if you are using JBOSS app server then it can be done in db2-ds.xml file.